# Describe only shape of an object in typescript, but ignore the types

Tags: typescript

I want to describe the following object shape in typescript, but I want to ignore the types of the fields.

```
interface TestInterface {
  TestOne?: string;
  TestTwo?: number;
  TestThree?: boolean;
}
```

My idea was to describe it in the following way:

```
type Shape = { [fieldName: string]: any };

type ShapeType<TShape extends Shape> = TShape;

var test: ShapeType<TestInterface> = {
  TestThree: "asdf",
}
```

It should complain about something like:

```
var test: ShapeType<TestInterface> = {
    TestThree: "asdf",
    TestFour: "123",
}
```

If I typecast "asdf" to any it works. Is there a way to describe this in a way that casting is not needed?

Edit: The idea behind it is to have a shape that is normally used for data exchange but on special occations it will be used for metadata. In those cases I only care about the structure, but not about the type (at least for now - the idea would be to change the types of the shape to another given type).

Answer (score 3):

*As a concept, I do not see advantage of declaring something to be **`boolean`** and assigning it as a **`string`**...*

But we can adjust it like this:

```
//type ShapeType<TShape extends Shape> = TShape;
interface Shape { [fieldName: string]: any };

// now, TestInterface also contains [fieldName: string]
interface TestInterface extends Shape {
  TestOne?: string;
  TestTwo?: number;
  TestThree?: boolean;
}


type ShapeType<TShape extends Shape> = TShape;

// BTW - why we declared TestsThree to be boolean
// if we assign it to string... that would hardly help
var test: ShapeType<TestInterface> = {
    TestsThree: "asdf",
}
```

Or, if we do not want to have a Shape to be interface,

```
// we have to do this explicitly [fieldName: string]
interface TestInterface {
  [fieldName: string]: any 
  TestOne?: string;
  TestTwo?: number;
  TestThree?: boolean;
}

type Shape = { [fieldName: string]: any };

type ShapeType<TShape extends Shape> = TShape;

var test: ShapeType<TestInterface> = {
    TestsThree: "asdf",
}
```

*Both approaches will work, but again.. Why we would define **TestThree?: boolean;** and then assign it as `TestsThree: "asdf",`?*

Comment: Regarding the why: Normally the shape should be used to exchange data, but I would also like to put metadata on those fields. So for that reason I would like to reuse the shape.

Comment: The solution seems to have the problem that it allows to add new fields like "TestFour" without complaining.

Answer (score 1):

This was made ages ago, but I ran into a similar issue. You seem to want a type for an object that has the same properties, but typed as any instead of whatever they are.

```
type ShapeType<T> = { [key in keyof T]?: any };

//fine
const test1: ShapeType<TestInterface> = {
    TestsThree: "asdf",
}
//error "TestFour" is not a valid property
const test2: ShapeType<TestInterface> = {
    TestThree: "asdf",
    TestFour: "123",
}
```